# How do I properly call a method inside a method inside the same class?

Tags: java, processing

I am writing some code in processing to display a random walker using the [Monte Carlo algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_algorithm).

Now I have specified a walker class with inside two important methods a step function which controls the movement and a stepsize function which controls the speed and direction.

But for some reason I cannot properly call the stepsize method in the step method. As a result,the program draws nothing on the screen. The code executes, I have no errors.

My code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Walker {
    float y;
    float x;
    float monte_carlo;

    Walker() {
        x = width/2;
        y= height/2;
    }

    void display(){
        stroke(0);
        point(x,y);
    }

    float stepsize (float r1) {
        while (true) {
            r1 = random(0,10);
            float probability = r1;
            float r2 = random(0,10);
            if (r2 < probability) {
                return r1;
            }
        }
    }

    void step() {
        x += stepsize(monte_carlo);
        y += stepsize(monte_carlo);
    }   
}

Walker w;

void setup() {
    size(400,400);
    w = new Walker();
    background(255);
}

void draw() {  
    w.display();
    w.step();
}
```

This problem has been bothering me for a while and I would really appreciate it if someone could enlighten me!

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I got no errors and the code executes, but it doesn't draw anything on the screen.

Comment: Are you receiving compilation errors? monte_carlo isn't initialized properly when you pass it to stepsize() and the variable r1 is useless since it just gets overwritten by the random method.

Comment: Well, this program should draw something on the screen. The reason why it won't do that is that the monte carlo variable I declared in the class doesn't get modified and therefore the x and y variables in the step method won't either. I think I've said it wrong. The dot is being drawn, but it doesn't move.

Comment: rosscowar could you explain that? How is monte carlo not initialized properly? I'm not getting any compilation errors. I actually want it to be overwritten by the random method because I want random movement. Or am I not getting what you are saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is [pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference), so your `stepsize()` method will not modify your `monte_carlo` variable. Just use the variable directly in the method instead of passing it in.

```
float stepsize () {
    while (true) {
        monte_carlo = random(0,10);
        float probability = monte_carlo;
        float r2 = random(0,10);
        if (r2 < probability) {
            return monte_carlo;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this since I come from another programming language. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

You are always calling `stepsize(0.0f)` whenever `stepsize(monte_carlo)` is called, because `float monte_carlo;` means the variable is initialized with its default value (which is `0.0f`) and you never modify it in your code.

Also, since you never use the value passed to the `stepsize()` function, you should use this signature instead :`float stepsize()`.